# Steam Group XML - Change Time Zone

Tags: xml, events, steam

I'm accessing event details with the provided XML from Steam, because there's no API alternative.

http://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791434287866/events?xml=1&action=eventFeed&month=6&year=2015

How can I change the time zone of the events? Do I have to append a parameter to the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the time zone is hardcoded. 
I solved this problem with a regular expression (look for times) and `str_replace` to replace the match with a new defined (+8 hours) time.

It's a bit messy but I don't see any other way to do this since Steam Groups are not part of the Web-Api.